# Sagemaker "Could not find model data" when trying to deploy my model

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a training script in Sagemaker like,

```
def train(current_host, hosts, num_cpus, num_gpus, channel_input_dirs, model_dir, hyperparameters, **kwargs):
    ... Train a network ...
    return net

def save(net, model_dir):
    # save the model
    logging.info('Saving model')
    y = net(mx.sym.var('data'))
    y.save('%s/model.json' % model_dir)
    net.collect_params().save('%s/model.params' % model_dir)

def model_fn(model_dir):
    symbol = mx.sym.load('%s/model.json' % model_dir)
    outputs = mx.symbol.softmax(data=symbol, name='softmax_label')
    inputs = mx.sym.var('data')
    param_dict = gluon.ParameterDict('model_')
    net = gluon.SymbolBlock(outputs, inputs, param_dict)
    net.load_params('%s/model.params' % model_dir, ctx=mx.cpu())
    return net
```

Most of which I stole from the [MNIST Example](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/mxnet_gluon_mnist/mnist.py).

When I train, everything goes fine, but when trying to deploy like,

```
m = MXNet("lstm_trainer.py", 
          role=role, 
          train_instance_count=1, 
          train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
          hyperparameters={'batch_size': 100, 
                         'epochs': 20, 
                         'learning_rate': 0.1, 
                         'momentum': 0.9, 
                         'log_interval': 100})
m.fit(inputs) # No errors
predictor = m.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

I get, ([full output](https://gist.github.com/aidan-plenert-macdonald/7eb7ba7402790b61596938b5cbf605b6))

```
INFO:sagemaker:Creating model with name: sagemaker-mxnet-py2-cpu-2018-01-17-20-52-52-599
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ... Stack dump ...
ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateModel operation: Could not find model data at s3://sagemaker-us-west-2-01234567890/sagemaker-mxnet-py2-cpu-2018-01-17-20-52-52-599/output/model.tar.gz.
```

Looking in my S3 bucket `s3://sagemaker-us-west-2-01234567890/sagemaker-mxnet-py2-cpu-2018-01-17-20-52-52-599/output/model.tar.gz`, I in fact don't see the model.

What am I missing?

Comment: Might be missing some configuration. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/mxnet-example1-prepare.html

Comment: And, you shouldn't have to even include the save / model_fn in your .py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling the training job you should specify the output directory:

```
#Bucket location where results of model training are saved.
model_artifacts_location = 's3://<bucket-name>/artifacts'

m = MXNet(entry_point='lstm_trainer.py',
          role=role,
          output_path=model_artifacts_location,
          ...)
```

If you don't specify the output directory the function will use a default location, that it might not have the permissions to create or write to.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue using a different Estimator in a very similar way on Sagemaker.

My issue was after the first deployment on a re-deploy I had to delete the old "Endpoint Configuration" - which was confusingly pointing the endpoint to an old model location. I imagine this could be done from python using the AWS API, although very easy to test on the portal if this is the same issue.

[image]